# How can I store Hex Values in Memory address using NFC on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter app where using NFC I have to write the Values from a LIST in specific bytes. I am using the Flutter NFC Plugin:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit

```
List<int> value = [253, 165, 6, 147, 164];
var result = hex.encode(value);
```

I need to be able to store Hex Values in specific Address location using NFC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```dart
await FlutterNfcKit.writeNDEFRawRecords([NDEFRawRecord("253", "165", "6", "147", "164", ndef.TypeNameFormat.unknown)]);
```

as stated in the plugin's page documentation?